# Can Windows 98's command.com be considered as a virtual machine?

Tags: windows, dos

I was just playing around with OSs from DOS to Windows 98 and a question came to my mind : I've always seen `cmd.exe` in Windows XP and later as a shell (like in any Unix). But, when I discovered `command.com` in Windows 98, it seemed like a totally different thing (even though it seems that *visually* there's no difference). And since there's a way to "hide" Windows from the prompt perspective, then can `command.com` program in Windows 98 be just considered as a virtual machine/emulator emulating DOS and not as a standalone shell ?

Comment: No. It is neither a VM or a DOS emulator.

Comment: Can you please motivate your answer? What would be then the difference between a "real" DOS emulator for Windows 98 and `command` ?

Comment: It *uses* a VM, just like any other 16-bit DOS program.  Press Alt+Enter to make that more visible.

Comment: Sorry. My comment was based on your original question before your edit to clarify. Yes, ancient and long since extinct OSs did things differently. You do realize that Win98 was...well, nearly 20 years ago? Who cares what it did?

Comment: Just as a hobby, in my spare time I'm currently doing some research on old software in order to better understand choices made in newer software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cmd.exe` is just a shell, no virtual machine involved.

But the old `command.com` was a different beast -- it was a 16-bit DOS application, and ran in Windows' [virtual DOS machine (VDM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_DOS_machine).

- Windows 98 had only `command.com`.
- 32-bit versions of Windows NT/2000/XP/etc. have both `cmd.exe` and `command.com` installed.
- 64-bit versions of Windows do not have a VDM and have only `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Yeah, since `command.com` emulates a totally different architecture from its host system, I knew something bigger than just a shell was involved in there. Thank you for the clarifications!

Comment: @RyanB You missed the point, `command.com` doesn't emulate anything. It's an 16 MS-DOS application. It's a standalone shell, just one written for a different operating system. Under WIndows NT/2000/XP/etc it runs under NTVDM which emulates MS-DOS. Under Windows 95/98/ME it runs under MS-DOS in a VM.